Passing Edge Vertex Vector Attribute from One object to another
So I was hoping I could update an Objects position Based off the Vertex of another Object without having to Instance it. Here's my Setup:


I was hoping the Result would be Something like this:

But I'm guessing there are rules that Attributes can and cannot Pass? and if so, is there a way I could Update the position via a Python Script or maybe a Different Geometry node setup?

Does this answer your question? How to have object A attribute influence object B shader parameters

in order to "pass" info from an object to another you can import the first object in the second node tree (clic and drag) then mesure it there.

And you can still have transformation on the first object with Geometry Node.

I hope it helps.


This is Amazing! could this be done with Geometry Node groups In Lieu of Object Info as well?
